Integrating $\int\frac{3x^{2}+4x-1}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{2}\sqrt{x+1}} dx$
I am stuck on this integral: $$I = \int\frac{3x^{2}+4x-1}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{2}\sqrt{x+1}} dx$$ for quite a while now. I am only supposed to use elementary operations (algebraic manipulation, trig sub, by-parts etc.). Subbing $t=\sqrt{x+1}$ does not seem to be of much help as the end form is a $\frac{quartic}{(quartic)^2}$ which won't break into partial fractions.  And that brings me here. The presence of $(x^2+1)^2$ in the denominator suggests to me that the integral is of the form: $$\frac{f(x)}{(x^2+1)}$$ which indeed checks out as I plug in the integral into wolframalpha to get: $$I=-\frac{2\sqrt{x+1}}{(x^2+1)}+c$$ However, that seems to be of little help ( as of now). So, I'd like to start off with some hints before the entire solution. Any help is much appreciated.

HINT: Note that
$$
\frac{3x^2+4x-1}{(x^2+1)^2\sqrt{x+1}} = \frac{4x(x+1)-(x^2+1)}{(x^2+1)^2\sqrt{x+1}} = 2 \sqrt{x+1}\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2} - \frac{1}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+1}} = 2\sqrt{x+1}\left( -\frac{1}{x^2+1} \right)'-\frac{1}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+1}},
$$
then split into two integrals and compute the first one using integration by parts.

That's some serious manipulation right there. It does lead me to the answer. However, though the integration is doable, it is undeniably ugly, involving the use of complex partial fractions. Honestly subbing t=$\sqrt{x+1}$ yields a rather similar form.

$$I = \int\frac{3x^{2}+4x-1}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{2}\sqrt{x+1}}\, dx$$
$$\sqrt{x+1}=t \quad\implies\quad x=t^2-1 \quad\implies\quad dx=2t\,dt$$ Then
$$I=\int \frac{6 t^4-4 t^2-4}{\left(t^4-2 t^2+2\right)^2}\,dt$$
Now, write
$$t^4-2t^2+2=(t^2-a)(t^2-b)\qquad \text{where} \qquad (a,b)=1\pm i $$ and use partial fraction decomposition
$$A=\frac{6 t^4-4 t^2-4}{\left(t^4-2 t^2+2\right)^2}=\frac{6 t^4-4 t^2-4}{(t^2-a)^2\,(t^2-b)^2}$$
$$A=\frac{2}{(a-b)^2}\Big(\frac{3 a^2-2a-2}{\left(t^2-a\right)^2}
+\frac{3b^2-2 b-2}{\left(t^2-b\right)^2}  \Big)+$$
$$\frac{4 (3 a b-a-b-2)}{(a-b)^3} \Big(\frac{1}{t^2-b}-\frac{1}{t^2-a}  \Big)$$ Now, one integration by parts gives
$$\int \frac{1}{\left(t^2-c\right)^2}\,dt = \frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{c}}\right)}{2 c^{3/2}}-\frac{t}{2 c
   \left(t^2-c\right)}$$
Now, it becomes simple
